# yarn warning " > bootstrap@4.x.x" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3"

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm, yarnpkg, react-bootstrap

When we run `yarn` in a project with no `node_modules` directory, we get the following warning message during the dependency installs:

```
warning " > bootstrap@4.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
warning " > bootstrap@4.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.0".
```

However, it appears that `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` works fine without doing anything to fix these 2 warnings. `package.json` also do not contain entries for these 2 packages.

**Question:** Why does Bootstrap and related files appear to continue working despite having unmet peer dependencies?

Isn't the whole point of `yarn` and `npm` be to manage these dependencies?

What is the proper way to resolve these warnings?

---

**Part of packages.json**

```
{
  ...

  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",

    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jquery` and `popper.js` are used by Bootstrap for their Javascript components (dropdown, modal etc). However: If you only use the CSS part - you do not need these. That is probably why they are listed as "peer-dependencies".

There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30329) to mute theses warnings. They are just warnings afterall.

`react-bootstrap` does not need/replaces `jquery` but it uses [popper](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/blob/2f966b616d959df90c4e16e69f843634eb1774e0/package.json#L64) in another Version (`@popperjs/core`) for tooltip placement. That is why everything is working - even though Bootstrap is missing some "peer-dependencies". Libraries like `(react|vue|ng)-bootstrap` usually only use the CSS part of Bootstrap and rewrite the Javascript part entirely.

> What is the proper way to resolve these warnings?

To my understanding: You will have to add them as dependencies in your project - even though you do not actually need them. Or... Ignore the warnings.